# apacite: replace "et al." when citing multi-authored papers

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

Is there a way to replace "et al." abbreviation with its counterpart in another language (Turkish) which has no default `turkish.apc` file. I'd like to replace my citations to papers with more than 2 authors with "vd." instead of "et al."

Comment: If you take a look at the other `.apc` files, you can create your own for Turkish quite easily.  If you put it in your local `texmf` folder (inside `/tex/latex/apacite`) it will be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's likely you will need other changes to adapt to Turkish, it would be best to create your own `turkish.apc` file based on some of the others that are already distributed with the package.

But you can change the `et al.` string by adding the following to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{vd.\hbox{}}%       et al
\renewcommand{\BOthersPeriod}[1]{vd.\hbox{}}%  et al.
```